# #SUGBELUX - Sitecore Analytics where are we at and Sitecore HELIX 101

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

## Event details:

```
Starts: Thursday, 16 March 2017, 06:00 PM (CET)
Ends: Wed, 16 March 2017, 09:00 PM (CET)
```

## Location:

Delaware offices
Uitbreidingstraat 2
Antwerp
Belgium

## Event Details

```
Register here: https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belgium/events/237188011/
```

## Agenda

The SUG board members would like to welcome you to Tenth Sitecore User Group event (BeLux). Time to see what Sitecore pushes forward as their best approaches and now that MongoDB and Sitecore XP have been around for a while let's see what Analytics has offered us.

### Session 1: Sitecore Analytics - Where are we at?

Sitecore Introduced their Analytics platform way back as the OMS. It has since changed a lot both in name and in functionality as well as technology. Currently the DMS functionality is driven by MongoDB and allows you to capture a wide range of interactions. But are we using these correctly? Can it be used for all customers/websites? What are our main findings, what do customers refer to, and what is the product evolving into?

General presentation and Q&A

#### Speaker: Kris Verheire

### • Session 2: Sitecore HELIX 101

Where Sitecore used to work based on a more Page type oriented approach, the recent years and versions have shown a drastic change into a more Component driven approach. Allowing you to create content and apply it across the entire website. Technically, Sitecore has also been hard put to create a number of development guidelines that stretch into both the backend item structure as well as the solution on top of Sitecore.

We will provide an overview of the HELIX basics, focussing on The What, The Why, The Good, The Bad and The Ugly.

General Presentation and Q&A

#### Speaker: Jeremy Coste